# How to give parameters for sending transaction in solana using python?

Tags: python, transaction

I'm trying to create the transaction in solana when I give my secreet seed as input it throws an error that fromSeed() takes 32 bytes input my code is below.

```
def Send_Transaction(sender_seed, recepient, amount):
    print(len(sender_seed))
    # Sender_Secret_Key    = bytes(sender_key ,'utf-8')
    print("SENDER KEY Converted: ", sender_seed)
    sender = Keypair.from_seed(sender_seed)
    txn = Transaction().add(transfer(TransferParams(from_pubkey=sender.public_key, to_pubkey=PublicKey(recepient), lamports=amount)))

    tx =http_client.send_transaction(txn, sender) # doctest: +SKIP

    print(tx['result'])



secSeed = d0dad8b1b476c6249a3b3302421c346c0b8698d38f64317a0ed04d2171464a90
secSeed = bytes(secSeed ,'utf-8')
# print(secSeed.fromhex())


Send_Transaction( secSeed,
'FuYTEtJFFPQGpGjzTgVrQ4RyZg8V1hQbPJCfXtLFVnrs',10)
```

Comment: Could you please share the on chain code as well.

Comment: what's on chain code?

Comment: Who are you sending the transactions to ? Can you show me the complete code.

Comment: I'm sending to this address
"FuYTEtJFFPQGpGjzTgVrQ4RyZg8V1hQbPJCfXtLFVnrs"